# Structuremap 2.6.1 bootstrapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I'm using StructureMap 2.6.1
This is the code from Bootstrapper.cs:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>());
```

When I run application, I get the following exception:

> No Default Instance defined for
>   PluginFamily
>   IFoo,
>   Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

I don't get an exception when I use this obsolete code:

```
ForRequestedType<IFoo>()
                .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<Foo>();
```

Can anyone tell me the latest syntax for ObjectFactory's initializer?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you call Initialize, you're resetting the ObjectFactory. I.e. in the following scenario:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>());
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.For<IBaz>().Use<Baz>());
```

You've only actually mapped out `IBaz` to `Baz`.

You should use an ApplicationRegistry instead:

```
public class ApplicationRegistry : Registry
{
    public ApplicationRegistry()
    {
        For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>();
        For<IBaz>().Use<Baz>();
    }
}
```

And use that in your Initialize method:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.AddRegistry(new ApplicationRegistry()));
```

Comment: I can map many items if I separate them by coma. The problem is that ObjectFactorz.Initiaze doesn't work in the ApplicationRegistry class. Can you tell me how to to pass argument to the constructor? I want to hard code it. The obsolete syntax was WithCtorArg("comeValue").EqualTo("someValue")

Comment: Pass an argument to which constructor?

Comment: Any class. For<Foo>().Use<Foo>().WithCtorArg("someValue").EqualTo("someValue");

Comment: No idea, not done that yet. I suggest you ask a new question as that's totally different to the question asked here.

Comment: It is: For<Foo>().Use<Foo>().Ctor<string>("someValue").Is("someValue");